# Saving image to asset folder, for use in other scenes. Not working in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm quite new to unity and I'm hoping some more experienced people can help me out. I've built an app that has a basic drawing interface that let's the user draw and then click a save button. At this point I create a new texture made of a screenshot and save it to a png as follows.

```
File.WriteAllBytes (Application.dataPath + "/Graphics/Tester-" + count + ".png", bytes);
```

This works completely fine on the editor and saves to my graphics folder within my assets folder. I call for an UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.Refresh so that in later scenes I can use these newly saved images to update and replace the placeholders that I've positioned in other scenes. This means that the user can see their drawing throughout the game. Again, this works a treat on the standalone.

My problem comes from trying to port the app onto an ipad, I can't seem to find a way to both save the image on iOS and yet also allow it to overwrite an existing asset when updated for the remaining scenes. I've tried example with persistentDatapath which I can use to save an image on iOS successfully, but I don't understand how to deal with the second and very important part of the problem, which is the asset refreshing over itself within other scenes.

I'm very lost as to how to proceed and am looking for some guidance. I hope I've adequately explained the issue and that people can understand. If any more details or clarification are required, I'll do my best to do so.

Thanks in advance, N.

Comment: UnityEditor is for editor, you can't and you don't need to Refresh in game. Since you can save images, just load that image from file path as texture then replace your placeholder's texture.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual for Application.dataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) states that on iOS it is read only and you should be using `Application.persistentDataPath`anyway.

Here is a working demo:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/// <summary>
/// Saving and loading data to a persistent data path
/// </summary>
public class LoadSaveCheck : MonoBehaviour {

    public static void Save(string name, byte[] bytes) {
        var path=System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, name);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (path, bytes);
    }

    public static byte[] Load(string name) {
        var path=System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, name);
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (path);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Test - writing and reading a text file. Should work with any byte stream (like the one from Texture2D.EncodeToPNG)
    /// </summary>
    void Start() {
        Debug.Log ("Application.persistentDataPath=" + Application.persistentDataPath, this);

        Debug.Log ("saving...", this);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("test test test");
        Save ("test.txt", bytes);

        Debug.Log ("loading...", this);
        var loadedBytes = Load ("test.txt");
        var str=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (loadedBytes);
        Debug.Log ("got string: " + str, this);
    }


}
```